# Passing a shell script variable into an AWK command

Tags: shell-script, awk

I want to be able to call a shell script contining the following command.

```
awk -F $'\xE7' '{OFS ="¬"} { $3 = sprintf("%010s". $3) ; print $0 }' > outputfile
```

But I want to be able to pass a shell script variable into this command which will be used to replace the `$3` within the AWK command.

How do I pass a shell script variable into this AWK command?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Single quotes inhibit expansion. Switch them up.

```
awk ... '...'"$foo"'...' ...
```

Comment: No! This treats the value of `foo`, surrounded by double quotes, as a piece of awk script. If `$foo` contains double quotes or backslashes, all hell may break loose. See [Dennis's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/203819/passing-a-shell-script-variable-into-an-awk-command/204055#204055) for a solution that works.

Comment: @Gilles: There is no surrounding by double quotes. The shell removes all external quotes before passing, and since the single quotes are closed before the double quotes are opened and vice versa, they are considered external quotes.

Comment: Oh, right, I'd misparsed your quotes, and what you wrote is sort-of sensible — the value of `foo` becomes a fragment of awk script — but then I don't see how it answers the question. @mattm123: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, but if you were thinking of using the contents of a shell variable as a string in awk, see Dennis's answer.

Comment: Gilles is right that if `$foo` can contain unsanitized values, it may seriously mess up your script.

Comment: ... Consider what happens to `awk '$1=='"$foo"'{print $3}'` when `$foo` evaluates to `z{next} {print "garbage"} 0`. And even in the ordinary case where `$foo` contains an ordinary string, you'll have to make sure your script places `"`s around it. Dennis' answer shows the right way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to do this is using AWK's variable passing feature. Also, you probably only need to set `OFS` once, so you should do it in the `BEGIN` clause.

```
awk -F $'\xE7' -v awkvar="$shellvar" 'BEGIN {OFS ="¬"} { $3 = sprintf("%010s". $3) ; print $0, awkvar }' input file > outputfile
```

You could also use `-v` to set `OFS`:

```
awk -F $'\xE7' -v awkvar="$shellvar" -v OFS ="¬" '{ $3 = sprintf("%010s". $3) ; print $0, awkvar }' input file > outputfile
```

I just added the variable to the `print` statement since I didn't know exactly how you wanted to use it.

Comment: @Gilles: Quotes aren't necessary for that type of assignment.

Comment: Huh? As far as the shell is concerned, `awkvar="$shellvar"` is the fifth word in the simple command. Without quotes, `awkvar=$shellvar` would undergo field splitting and pathname expansion as usual.

Comment: @Gilles: You are right. Sorry, I was thinking about normal shell assignment rules.

Answer (score 2):

awk has `ENVIRON` array for accessing environment:

```
$ FOO=bar awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["FOO"]}'
bar
```

Comment: This also works, but the `-v` technique is the preferred general solution.