# Using bash variables in the awk code

Tags: bash, awk

The following function written in bash incorporates AWK code carying out math operation on the multi-column data and eventually saves the results in the output file for all processed CSVs.

```
home="$PWD"
# folder with the outputs
rescore="${home}"/rescore 
# folder with the folders to analyse
storage="${home}"/results_bench
cd "${storage}"
# pattern of the csv file located inside each of sub-directory of "${storage}"
str='*str1.csv'

     rescore_data3 () {
str_name=$(basename "${str}" .csv)
mkdir -p "${rescore}"/"${str_name}"
# loop all directories contained target csv file
while read -r d; do
awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '
    FNR==1 {
        if (suffix)                             # suppress the empty line
            printf "%s %.3f (%d)\n", suffix, dGmin, dGminid
                                                # report the results for dGmin
        dGmin = ""                              # initialize the min value
        path=FILENAME
        sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"",path)
        prefix=suffix=FILENAME
        sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
        sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix); sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
        if (FNR==NR)
            print "lig(CNE)" " " "dG(" prefix ")" " " "ClusterID"        # print the header line
        next
    }
    {
        dG = sqrt((($3+10)/10)^2+(($2-100)/100)^2)
        if (dGmin == "" || dG < dGmin) {
            dGmin = dG                          # update the min dG value
            dGminid = $1                        # update the ID with the min dG
        }
    }
    END {
        printf "%s %.3f (%d)\n", suffix, dGmin, dGminid # report results for dGmin
    }
' "${d}_"*/${str} > "${rescore}/"${str_name}"/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
}
```

Basically each processed CSV cointains3 columns:

```
#input_str1.csv located in the folder 10V1_cne_lig12
ID, POP, dG
1, 142, -5.6500 # the line with ID=1, has lowest value in dG
2, 10, -5.5000
3, 2, -4.9500
4, 150, -4.1200
```

Applying rescore_data3() on 5 CSV files produces the following output (individual line contains info regarding individual csv):

```
# 10V1.csv
lig dG(10V1) ID
lig12 0.947 (1)
lig40 0.595 (1)
lig199 1.060 (1)
lig211 0.756 (2)
lig278 0.818 (1)
```

I need to modify the constant numbers (10 and 100) in the math equation of the AWK code to use substitute them on flexible variables computed for all processed csv files: 10 should be substituted to the lowest value of dG (3rd column of each input.csv) and 100 should be substituted to the highest value of the POP (the 2nd column of each input.csv). Eventually the modified math equation in AWK script should still contain $2 and $3 vars (taken info for particular csv) as well as ${the_lowest_dG} and ${the_highest_POP} (computed at the begining only once for ALL CSVs):

```
dG = sqrt((($3-{the_lowest_dG})/{the_lowest_dG})^2+(($2-{the_highest_POP})/{the_highest_POP})^2)
```

**EDITED:**
Here is a possible solution integrated into my function based on the AWK code that was kindly proposed by glenn jackman. In order to calculate lowest_dG and highest_POP **for ALL input CSVs**  , I used this awk code just before my AWK function (which also has been updated to accept these two variables and uses it further in the math equation):

```
rescore_data4 () {
# name of the target CSV file to be rescored
str_name=$(basename "${str}" .csv)
#make dir for output 
mkdir -p "${rescore}"/"${str_name}"
**# 1 - calculate max POP and dGmin for ALL rescored CSVs at once**
read highestPOP lowestDG < <(
    awk -F ', ' '
        FNR == 1 {next}
        NR == 2 || $2 > pop {pop = $2}
        NR == 2 || $3 < dg  {dg  = $3}
        END {print pop, dg}
    ' "${storage}"/*_*_*/${str} ## < applied on all *.csv files in each of the subdirectory matching *_*_* pattern
)
printf >&2 'DEBUG INFO: this is topPOP= %d and dGmin= %.1f computed for %s...  ' "${highestPOP}" "${lowestDG}" "${str_name}"; sleep 0.1 
#
# 2- Apply the following AWK code for rescoring and final data collecting
while read -r d; do
# run rescoring routine using the min/max values 
awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' -v highest_POP="$highest_POP" -v lowest_dG="${lowestDG}" '
    FNR==1 {
        if (suffix)                             # suppress the empty line
            #print suffix " " dGmin " (" dGminid ")"
            printf "%s %.3f (%d)\n", suffix, dGmin, dGminid
            #printf "%s %.3f (%d) %.3f (%d)\n", suffix, dGmin, dGminid, dGmax, dGmaxid
                                                # report the results
        dGmin = ""                              # initialize the min value
        
        path=FILENAME
        sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"",path)
        prefix=suffix=FILENAME
        sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
        sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix); sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
        if (FNR==NR)
            print "lig(CNE)" " " "dG(" prefix ")" " " "ClusterID"        # print the header line
            #print "lig(CNE)" " " "dGmin(" prefix ")" " " "ID(dGmin)" " " "dGmax(" prefix ")" " " "ID(dGmax)"         # print the header line
        next
    }
    {
        dG = sqrt((($3-lowest_dG)/lowest_dG)^2+(($2-240)/240)^2)
        if (dGmin == "" || dG < dGmin) {
            dGmin = dG                          # update the min dG value
            dGminid = $1                        # update the ID with the min dG
        }
    }
    END {
        #print suffix " " dGmin " (" dGminid ")"    # report the results
        printf "%s %.3f (%d)\n", suffix, dGmin, dGminid
        #printf "%s %.3f (%d) %.3f (%d)\n", suffix, dGmin, dGminid, dGmax, dGmaxid
    }
' "${d}_"*/${str} > "${rescore}/"${str_name}"/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
}
```

While this generally works well ,  there is a bug in the newly introduced awk part : sometimes the value of the lowestDG can not be computed in the case of a big number of input CSVs **containing more than 10 lines.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a shell script variable into an AWK command](https://superuser.com/questions/203819/passing-a-shell-script-variable-into-an-awk-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk, think of `$` as an operator used to fetch the value of the given field number. Awk variables, like C variables, do no need to be dereferenced with `$`.

```
awk -F', *'\
    -v OFS=', ' \
    -v the_highest_POP="the_highest_POP" \
    -v the_lowest_dG="$the_lowest_dG" \
'
    # ...
    dG = sqrt((($3 - the_lowest_dG) / the_lowest_dG)^2 + (($2 - the_highest_POP) / the_highest_POP)^2)
```

> Should I compute ${the_highest_POP} and ${the_lowest_dG} using bash (which handles all CSVs at once using while) , store them in external variables and provide them to awk, [...] or alternatively is it possible to do all steps directly in the AWK code

It depends entirely on `some_method_to_cumpute_highest_POP_for_all_csvs_in_d`

---

Ah, I see. I didn't read the question carefully. You are going to have to process the files twice, once to find the min/max values and again to do the dG calculations. For readability, I'd do that with 2 separate find/awk invocations:

```bsh
# get the files you want to operate on.
# I'm assuming there are not hundreds of them.
mapfile -t cvsFiles < <(
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' |
    awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
)

# get the min/max values
read highestPOP lowestDG < <(
    awk -F ', ' '
        FNR == 1 {next}
        NR == 2 || $2 > pop {pop = $2}
        NR == 2 || $3 < dg  {dg  = $3}
        END {print pop, dg}
    ' "${csvFiles[@]}"
)

# do the calculations over all the files
awk -F', *'\
    -v OFS=', ' \
    -v the_highest_POP="$highestPOP" \
    -v the_lowest_dG="$lowestDG" \
'...' "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you! so I integrated this in my bash function after while read -r d; do  removing an unused ")" in the mapfile command. I also upgraded my bash to the 5th version (there was no mapfile in the bash3 used by my MAC). Now technically the script works without errors BUT "${csvFiles[@]}" is empty, thus indicating that something went wrong. Note, each target csv file is located inside the directory $d, so initially find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*'   matched this directory and the csv file corresponds to the "${d}_"*/${str} recognized in my bash code

Comment: .. so I took the second command which uses read to compute directly $highestPOP, $lowestDG with the glob mask (that had been used by my AWK code initially): read highestPOP lowestDG < <(...."${d}_"*/${str}). Eventually  it produced 18 pairs of dGmin/popMAX, while I need only one corresponded to the two extremum values in all dataset :-)

Comment: Well, don't loop over the files. One awk command where you pass it all the filenames, as shown.

Comment: I've tried to modify in your AWK code END {print pop, dg} to END {printf "%d %.3f (%d)\n", pop, dg} indicating format of dG (it is floated number) but it did not help. The problem always related to calculating of dg variable in the case of big number of input CSV contained MANY lines (it appeared dg=0.000, which is wrong since we ae always dealing with NEGATIVE numbers in this column)...

Comment: OK OK I am going to create new topic related to calculation of MIN and MAX values since it is beyond the queistion of the ussage of bash variables in awk code that has been resolved! Cheers